# How to create an ElasticSearch Index as curl

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query to create an index:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/my-index-000002?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
   "mappings": {
      "athlete": {
         "properties": {
          "birthdate": {
           "type": "date",
           "format": "dateOptionalTime"
           },
           "location": {
               "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "rating": {
             "type": "integer"
          },
          "sport": {
             "type": "string"
          }
        }
     }
   }
}'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
   "root_cause": [
   {
     "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
     "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [athlete : {properties={birthdate={format=dateOptionalTime, type=date}, name={type=string}, rating={type=integer}, location={type=geo_point}, sport={type=string}}}]"
   }
  ],
  "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
  "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [athlete : {properties={birthdate={format=dateOptionalTime, type=date}, name={type=string}, rating={type=integer}, location={type=geo_point}, sport= {type=string}}}]",
  "caused_by": {
  "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
  "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [athlete : {properties={birthdate={format=dateOptionalTime, type=date}, name={type=string}, rating={type=integer}, location={type=geo_point}, sport={type=string}}}]"
}
},
"status": 400
}
```

I think my syntax for creating the index is incorrect. Grateful for any insights. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove `athlete` as there is [no need for any mapping type name](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html) anymore, the rest is fine:

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/my-index-000002?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
   "mappings": {                     
                                      <---- remove this line
         "properties": {
          "birthdate": {
           "type": "date",
           "format": "dateOptionalTime"
           },
           "location": {
               "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "name": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "rating": {
             "type": "integer"
          },
          "sport": {
             "type": "string"
          }
        }
   }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks. That plus I changed string to text. thanks